# linked list cant add to the list

Tags: c, linked-list

hey i need help for some reason i am missing the conection to the linked list
my list in the end only have the head but I dont find it

```
Number_Of_List* create_list(Number_Of_List* list)
{
    int number;
    Number_Of_List* temp ;

    printf("Enter numbers, for exit enter negative numbern");
    scanf_s("%d", &number);
    list->num = number;
    list->next = NULL;
    temp = list;
    while (number > 0)
    {
        temp->next = insertData(number);
        temp = temp->next;
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
    }
    return list; // in here only the head is returned
}

Number_Of_List* insertData(int num)
{
    Number_Of_List* temp = (Number_Of_List*)malloc(sizeof(Number_Of_List));
    temp->num = num;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}
int main()
{
    Number_Of_List* head= (Number_Of_List*)malloc(sizeof(Number_Of_List));
    head = create_list(head);
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get your question but the code seems to be working fine. I don't understand why are you getting list in the argument and returning it, also in the first iteration, you add the first number twice.

Comment: The question is that in the end i return the list but i have only the head in there

Comment: @shahar The name of the function  create_temp_list does not make any sense and only confuses readers of the code.

Comment: @vlad from Moscow ok i edited that thanks

Comment: @shahar Show how the function is called and how is defined its argument.

Comment: i posted an edit

Comment: I have tested your code and whole list was returned. How exactly are you testing your code?